How to use the new Hearing Aid feature for AirPods Pro 2 Update 7A305 with iOS 18?
How to use the new Hearing Aid feature that Apple told to be live within iOS 18 and an AirPods Pro 2 update (7A305) in September 2024?
AirPods Pro 2 could be used somehow as a hearing aid with using the conversation boost feature.
Apple announced that now with iOS 18 you need to do a hearing test and afterwards you can use them as a full hearing aid device.
I updated to iOS 18 and AirPods 7A305 but couldn't find such a feature.
How to access it?

I edited your post to remove the Q about when Apple would release this feature as it is off topic for AD. Asking why Apple does something or when it will be released is speculation and not suitable for AD. We stick to concrete problems/issues with Apple products that can be solved by the volunteers who help people out with their problems.

You can use the hearing test function on iOS 18.1 in the US.

Open the health app
Tap hearing


The initial release of iOS 18 isn’t the update you need to use on
supported hardware.
See:

Footnote 2 of Apple introduces AirPods 4 and the world’s first all-in-one hearing health experience with AirPods Pro 2
Coming soon headline on AirPods Pro 2: Hearing Health


The Hearing Test and Hearing Aid features are expected to be available fall 2024

My expectation is you need an iPhone purchased in a country among the “more than 100 countries and regions, including the United States, Germany, and Japan.” where one might reasonably expect to activate this. My second guess is it won’t matter where the AirPods 2 were sold, but that is pure speculation as Apple hasn’t made the official roll out public, hasn’t shipped the onboarding software for iOS 18.whatever.it.ends.up.being and hasn’t updated the “Coming soon” messaging on the feature page for the Hearing Test and Hearing Aid feature that is FDA approved for the US.
What we do know is, they’re not in iOS 18.0 or iOS 18.0.1 and “it will be available with a free software update.”

This is common behavior when Apple notes in its marketing materials that a feature will be available in “the fall” or the less certain wording of “expected to be available fall 2024”

To have your AirPods Pro 2 work as a hearing aid, you'll need its firmware to updated to 7B19, and iOS 18.1 installed on your iPhone or iPad. Today I installed iOS 18.1 in my phone, connected my AirPods Pro 2, and checked the AirPod settings that showed up in my phone. I followed the signs to the hearing test. I thought my house was fairly quiet, but I had to take the hearing test 4 times before it fully finished without being disturbed by some noise. In one case it seems to have been just a truck going by on the street; in another a notification blasted through the test (it says it puts you in airplane mode). Anyway, once I finished the test, which showed moderate hearing loss, I followed the steps to enable the hearing aid features - and my sound world got brighter and a bit louder! Sounds are more distinct. I'm looking forward to the big challenge: hearing the person I'm talking with in a noisy environment. (Also looking forward to having my cyclist ears de-waxed :-)
